# Parsing awkward date format

Tags: php, date, time

I'm currently scraping content from a website using PHP and YQL. I need to convert an awkward date format into a UNIX timestamp so it can be formatted into a MySQL compatible date. I have tried using strtotime() but to no avail. Maybe a regular expression is the answer?

**Examples of dates**

```
08Dec10
06Aug10
29Jul10
07Jun10
04May10
```

Dan

Comment: What about `substr($string, 0, 2); substr($string, 2, 2); ....`?

Comment: I'd also just do the substr route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.3+

Then then [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function is perfect for your needs..

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dMy', '08Dec10');
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the date, if you need it in a different format:

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

If you are ever able to use the DateTime functions, several available from 5.2+ and more added in 5.3 then you should. Compared to the other functional solutions, the DateTime approaches are much more readable.

Also in all solutions, whether functional or using the DateTime object, check the return values. Both createFromFormat and strptime return false on error. So you can log the error and determine what the issue was.

Answer (score 2):

***Note:** `strptime` is not available on Windows.*

---

One solution is to use [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php):

```
$parts = strptime($str, '%d%b%y');
```

and then you can pass the values to [`mktime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

```
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$parts['tm_mon']+1, $parts['tm_mday'], $parts['tm_year']+1900);
```

Comment: This seems like the most elegant option but sadly the strptime function isn't supported on windows servers.

Answer (score 0):

Break up the date components using substr and use strtotime to put it all together again.

```
<?php
strtotime('20'. substr($time, 5, 2). '-'. substr($time, 2, 3). '-'. substr($time, 0, 2));
?>
```